# Unable to scroll Android app with Appium using Java Client

Tags: java, android, scroll, scrollview, appium

I am unable to scroll down to the bottom of any page in an Android app using Appium.  Multiple approaches were attempted, including those found on Stack Overflow.  (It seems this challenge is common.)  However, all attempts failed.

Environment:

- Appium version: 1.6.2
- Appium client: Java (java-client-6.1.0.jar)
- Android versions: 5.1, 6.0.1, 7.1.1
- Java version: jre1.8.0_171
- Selenium version: selenium-java-3.13.0
- App type: Cordova (hybrid); the app is built with Cordova but when running `System.out.println(driver.getContext());`, the result is `NATIVE_APP`

Please share any alternatives or refinements that can solve this problem.  Any helpful suggestions are greatly appreciated!

The following summarizes the various approaches that were attempted:

1. Approach: scrollIntoView() (various implementations)
  `driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(resourceId(\"send-to-email-app\"));").click();`
  - Source: Udemy course
  - Error: Does not scroll and NO error
2. Approach: Try catch > scrollIntoView()
  `try {
              driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"Send\"))");
          }catch(Exception e) {
              System.out.println("We got an error scrolling!");
          }`
  - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658626/how-to-scroll-top-to-botton-using-android-driver
  - Error: Partially works: the page scrolls down but not far enough
3. Approach: Swipe
  `driver.swipe(0, Startpoint,0,scrollEnd,1000);`
  - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130591/swipe-or-scroll-to-bottom-in-appium-android
  - Error: Swipe is deprecated
4. Approach: touchAction.longPress + moveTo
  `...touchAction.longPress(fromX, fromY).moveTo(toX, toY).release().perform();`
  - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282417/how-to-scroll-with-appium-1-7-1-using-touchaction
  - Error: "driver cannot be resolved"
5. Approach: touchAction.longPress + moveTo
  `TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
  touchAction.longPress(10, 10).moveTo(x, y).release().perform();`
  - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282417/how-to-scroll-with-appium-1-7-1-using-touchaction
  - Error: "The method longPress(LongPressOptions) in the type TouchAction is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)"
6. Approach: touch.longPress + moveTo
  `...TouchAction touch = new TouchAction(driver);
  touch.longPress(co_ordinates[0], co_ordinates[1]).moveTo(dinates[0], dinates[1]).release().perform();`
  - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304699/how-to-scroll-to-specific-element-inlatest-version-of-appium-using-java
  - Error: "takeaway cannot be resolved"
7. Approach: moveTo + using coordinates
  `actions.press(startX, startY).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).moveTo(endX, endY).release().perform();`
  - Source: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-scroll-examples/
  - Error: The 'press' action is deprecated!
8. Approach: Using Press Approach to swipe + moveTo
  `TouchAction().press(el0).moveTo(el1).release();`
  - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004686/scroll-text-area-with-terms-and-conditions-on-hybrid-app-with-appium
  - Error: "The method press(AndroidElement) is undefined for the type Object"
9. Approach: touchAction 'tap' using coordinates
  `TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
  touchAction.tap(PointOption.point(x, y)).perform();`
  - Source: https://discuss.appium.io/t/scrolling-to-element-in-android-app-using-java/17208
  - Error: None; it partially works: the page scrolls down but not far enough!
10. Approach: UiScrollable > Specify Parent scrollable frame and Child element
  `MobileElement doeButton = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
  "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().text(\"Android scrollbar test\")).getChildByText("
  + "new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.TextView\"), \"Doe\")"));`
  - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51003840/9214050
  - Error: "Could not parse UiSelector argument: problem using reflection to call this method"
11. Approach: UiScrollable > Specify Parent scrollable frame and 'scrollIntoView' child element
  `MobileElement sendEmailButton = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
                  "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"content\")).scrollIntoView("
                  + "new UiSelector().resourceId(\"add-task-button\"))"));
                  sendEmailButton.click();`
  - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51003840/9214050
  - Error: Does not scroll and NO error
12. Approach: Changed “scrollable” attribute for page elements from “false” to “true” using CSS styles
  - Source: http://burnignorance.com/html-tips/making-a-smooth-scroll-view-for-android-ios-in-html/
  - Error: none, but app won't scroll to bottom of page.
13. Approach: Touch actions: “mobile: swipe”, “mobile: scroll” (http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/)
  `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        HashMap params = new HashMap();
        params.put("direction", "up");
        js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", params);`
  - Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32387357/i-cant-make-swipe-gesture-work-for-me-in-appium-using-java#
  - Error: "Unknown mobile command "scroll". Only shell,startLogsBroadcast,stopLogsBroadcast commands are supported."
14. Approach: HashMap + scrollObject.put
  `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap();
  scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
  js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);`
  - Source: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/
  - Error: "Unknown mobile command "scroll". Only shell,startLogsBroadcast,stopLogsBroadcast commands are supported."
15. Approach: Adjusted context of app from "native" to "webview" (since it's a Cordova app)
  `appCapabilities.setCapability("autoWebview", "true");`
  - Source: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md
  - Error: "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible."
  - Error: "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '58.0.3029'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

Comment: Have you tried this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636520/android-appium-swipe-down-not-working/50636622#50636622

Comment: Consider trying my suggested answer in this recent similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537791/how-to-perform-scroll-up-and-down-in-android-for-latest-version-appium

Comment: @AlImran When attempting to adopt your method, Eclipse display the following with respect to press() in the last line: "The method press(PointOption) in the type TouchAction is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)". How can this be overcome? Thanks!

Comment: @BillHileman When attempting to adopt your first method, the following error is triggered by the `new TouchActions(driver)` line: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen".  Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I use AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> as my driver instantiation.  That might have something to do with it.  Check your appium java client version to make sure it's the latest version.  The server too.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (all of the Stack Exchange network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which require users to go to off-site links in order to have the context needed to answer are not useful to future visitors. This question might be good/useful, but the off-site data needs to be in the question.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for your comment. The off-site data was relocated to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a variation on the options proposed above, here is another way of implementing `TouchAction` in combination with `press` and `moveTo` methods that worked for me.  This results in a downward screen swipe.  You might need to simply adjust the coordinates to whatever works best on your client:

```
new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(550, 640)).waitAction().moveTo(PointOption.point(550, 60)).release().perform();
```

For additional info, you might check out these references:

- Appium site: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/
- Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rHe0r6YsVg

Comment: This is the solution I've been searching for!  I'd like to suggest a minor improvement: Instead of .press(...).waitAction() it works great for me by using only .longPress(...).  Appium's on-line documentation and examples left a lot to be desired, but your example made it crystal clear, thank you.  I was hung-up on the x/y point parameters, the docs just said "pointoptions" with no examples.

Answer (score 0):

(2024 update). Since touch actions are obsolete here is a new recommended way to do it.

```
var finger = new PointerInputDevice(PointerKind.Touch);
var dimensions = appiumDriver.Manage().Window.Size;
var locationX = (int)(dimensions.Width * 0.5);
var locationStartY = (int)(dimensions.Height * 0.9);
var locationEndY = (int)(dimensions.Height * 0.3);

var start = new Point(locationX, locationStartY);
var end = new Point(locationX, locationEndY);
var swipe = new ActionSequence(finger);
swipe.AddAction(finger.CreatePointerMove(CoordinateOrigin.Viewport, start.X, start.Y, TimeSpan.Zero));
swipe.AddAction(finger.CreatePointerDown(MouseButton.Left));
swipe.AddAction(finger.CreatePointerMove(CoordinateOrigin.Viewport, end.X, end.Y, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
swipe.AddAction(finger.CreatePointerUp(MouseButton.Left));
appiumDriver.PerformActions(new List<ActionSequence> { swipe });
```